# Creating rest api to handle specific request per second

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have to create an rest api ( lets call it W1) which will consume another licenced or paid rest api(W2). Licenced to consume the paid rest api is 150 request/second . But we have create our rest web service in such a way that it handle upto 500 request per second . How can we achieve that.

Comment: It depends. If each W1 request requires a W2 request (because of data modification) you need to license more. Or combine some requests of W1 to one W2 request. If W2 provides "static" data only, you can cache the response and answer similar request to W1 from the cache. This may work till 150 different W2 requests.

Comment: Your mention  " Or combine some requests of W1 to one W2 request". How can we do that ?

Comment: This depends on the provided W1 and W2 API. Maybe if you provide a call to return a resource and direct the call to W2. And W2 supports to return more than one resource with one call as a list. So you may combine some "get-resource" requests of W1 to one get list of resources requests in W2. Only an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write one tool to do one job and do it well.

You'll need to get and then cache the data, serving all 500r/s from that cache instead of a straight passthrough

So call it W0 is your data fetcher - it runs as its own process, etc. and gets data from W2 and inserts it into the local cache data store.  Basic stuff -  while true set a timestamp, get data, insert into local cache of data, get time stamp, if more than .5 seconds have elapsed repeat else wait a few ticks and check timestamp again and repeat

So W0 is feeding your database, pulling data at not more than 120 requests/sec (want to leave some room Just In Case).  W0 knows only about itself, and W2, and the write-to-database interface.

Your W1 is your RESTful API, reading data from the data cache that W0 is keeping topped up and fresh, and serving it out to your web app.  W1 knows nothing about W2, or needs to or cares to - it is only concerned with parsing client requests, authenticating them, validating them, running db queries, and sending appropriate output to clients.

W3->Wx are your application(s) that feed off of your RESTful API.  They know nothing about W0, W2, or the data store - all they care about is W1, your API.

Comment: So you are suggesting to use some in memory database. right ?

Comment: @IshantGaurav if you think that would work, I don't know any details about any of the actual apps involved or your infrastructure, budget, skill set, etc to make an educated guess.   Basic point is, separate your system into its pieces, and at some point you'll need to cache the data in some way to serve more clients than you've got licensed direct requests for....